# NoSQL or YesSQL

Tags: algorithm, full-text-search, nosql

I have a **huge** dictionary of words:

```
"word1" => [value1]
"word2" => [value2]
"word3" => [value3, value2]
...
"word400000000" => [value455, value3435, ..., value3423]
```

number of words is really big.

Now I want to be able to retrieve, really fast, all the `values` which are being pointed by `word`. `word` is string value.

What are the best tools to use? I thought of simple DB solution, but DBA guys said that it will not work *really fast*.

So, before I open [Cormen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)'s book, is there some ready solutions for that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RDMSs (YesSQL) you will most probably search values with `LIKE` or `=` operators on **all records**, i.e. search will take O(n). What you actually need is a data structure called **[inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)**, which allows you to find list of needed values in O(1). For description of structure and algorithms see Wikipedia article, for ready-to-use tools keep reading.

There's plenty of implementations of inverted index in **search engines** like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)/[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), [Sphinx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_%28search_engine%29) (which, by the way, supports several databases as data source), and also in some **key-value stores** like [Berkeley DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB) or [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/). Distinction between search engines and key-value stores is in that:

1. Search engines **implement inverted index more directly** (AFAIK, key-value DBs use [BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigtable)-like structures, that are much more complex then inverted index itself).
2. Search engines have a plenty of **tools for text analysis (parsing, stemming)**. I don't know, if you actually need it, but if you do, use search engines.
3. Key-value DBs are real databases. I.e., unlike search engines they have **real data types, not only strings**. Moreover, some of such DBs (e.g. Berkeley DB) can store programming language native data types without converting them to any inner format. So, if you need a real database with all features, use key-value stores.

Also note, that inverted index is really simple structure, so you can easily implement it by yourself, if none of previous options is suitable for you.

Answer (score 5):

Look at key/value storage engines such as Berkeley DB. They are very fast at that sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what behavior you want.  If you just want to be able to do an exact text search, then a hash table is probably a really great idea.  It has expected O(1) lookup, which is about as fast as you're going to get.

If you need the elements in sorted order (for example, so you can iterate across them in a reasonable order), then one of the myriad balanced search trees might be a good candidate; for example, a red-black tree or an AVL tree.

If you're working with a huge data set that can't all fit into main memory, then a very good choice might be a B-tree, which is a type of balanced binary search tree that minimizes the number of disk reads required to find a given element.  Most database systems use some flavor of B-trees for their lookups.

Comment: it means Cormen's book should be on my shelf. i.e. developing DB by myself (...time)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cassandra (http://cassandra.apache.org/). Is Easy to start, has pretty much documentation and is a really fast solution for your problem.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* that you will only want to search for values based on words and not the other way around, use a simple Key-Value store. Maybe **Redis** would be best.

If you think you will ever need to search based on the values, then you'll likely need Secondary Indices or off-line MapReduce jobs. Maybe **Cassandra** would be best.